# How to dynamically set defaultProps in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-props

Been trying to find a way to dynamically set the default props in React for the prop

```
Shop.defaultProps = {
  address: {props.address}
  status: 'open'
};
```

Is there anyway to set the default props dynamically?

Comment: Default props is only used if the prop is not provided. It wouldn't make any sense to set the defaults from the passed props.

Comment: What is your usecase of dynamically setting it ? why not straight away use `props.address` where you need it

Comment: Short answer : No! The whole idea is to have default values that are static isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React props are immutable, if you want to mutate something, then it needs to be in state.  Default props are there as more of a "guard" against a null/undefined value, or if you literally want a default value/setting.

If the prop is dynamic, it doesn't need to be "set", but rather address it later in the component via state.